# How do you use single quotes and possessive apostrophe on same word?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, quotation-marks

I'd like to write

> .. using OpenAI's GPT-3.5 Turbo model ..

except the word 'OpenAI' *must* be in single quotes (it's a requirement of the institution I'm writing for).

> 'OpenAI''s

seems like the most logical choice, but looks odd, and I don't think I've ever seen a double quote like that before (two `'` characters in a row).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree ‘Open AI’'s  doesn't look sleek and the two adjacent  punctuation marks might be mistaken for a typo. Is there a reason why you must use the possessive apostrophe?

> The ‘OpenAI’ ChatGPT 3.5-turbo model…

make the company's name a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

Consider inverting the order

> ChatGPT 3.5-turbo model **by** ‘OpenAI’ is…

Comment: Good idea about switching the order. From the organisation: "Please always write package names, software names and application
programming interface names in single quotes.
e.g: --> 'git'; 'OpenAI';"

Comment: @stevec  You don't need the possessive apostrophe either ”Clients using the latest ‘Apple’ iPhone…” With the possessive apostrophe it *sounds* a bit off: “Clients using the latest Apple's iPhone…”

Comment: Thanks, I like that idea a lot. I edited to: Using the 'OpenAI' 'GPT-3.5 Turbo' Large Language Model.

Comment: I'd note that wording beginning with *please* may not be the demand you read. Sounds like a request for a courtesy that, when it interferes with clear reading as here, you dispense with it.

Comment: @stevec OpenAI is a company name, not the name of a product or API; your style guide is wrong.

Comment: (Aside: "always write package names, software names and application programming interface names in single quotes". What an idiotic rule.)